# MySQL TRIGGER is not working with $wpdb->query when this trigger query is working well directly in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

HERE is my trigger query which is working fine when it is fired directly in mysql database,but when i use this query in wordpress then it doesn't work.
**so can you please give me some solution that how can i run this query with wordpress?**

```
drop trigger if exists table_1;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER table_1
AFTER 
INSERT ON table_2
FOR EACH ROW 
begin

INSERT INTO table_3 ( place_id, store_name, store_address) VALUES (new.place_id, new.store_name, new.vicinity);

end $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the creation of the trigger not working or is the trigger not triggering after you fire a query from wordpress?

Comment: trigger is working fine directly in mysql but when i use it with wordpress query then it doesn't work

Comment: That's not what I asked, are you trying to create the trigger through wordpress or have you already created it?

Comment: i am trying to create trigger through wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a trigger through wordpress you can't use the $wpdb->query() method as it doesn't support trigger creation queries. In fact the Wordpress wpdb API doesn't support this at all.

You'll have to expose the underlying mysqli API and use mysqli_multi_query by doing this:

```
mysqli_multi_query($wpdb->dbh, $your_trigger_query)
```

The mysqli_multi_query function uses the mysqli connection and does support the creation of triggers.

Comment: Hello i have tried this query which you given but it doesn't work and give me one notice and one warning.
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object 
Warning: mysqli_multi_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

Comment: Does your wpdb object exist?

Comment: yes i have included that wp-config file in that file so now that error doesn't appers but still it doesn't working because any trigger isn't created in database.

Comment: Do it without the DELIMITER, you don't need it for 1 trigger and te mysqli API doesn't support it. If you need to create multiple triggers then create them one by one